# PostgreSQL: split jsonb array on multiple columns with filter on object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

An example will explain better the goal.

Suppose I have a table with a jsonb column that is an array of objects:

```json
[
  {"value": "1", "fieldUsedToFilter": "A"}, 
  {"value": "5", "fieldUsedToFilter": "C"}, 
  {"value": "3", "fieldUsedToFilter": "B"}
]
```

What I want to do is query this column, keep only the object that contains the "fieldUsedToFilter" that is set to "A" or "B" and extract the value from the "value" field, i.e.:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

As you can see I skipped the C object and keep the values from objects A and B onethe same row.

P.S. the size of the array is unknown

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON path query.

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$[*] ? (@.fieldUsedToFilter == "A").value') #>> '{}' as a,
       jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$[*] ? (@.fieldUsedToFilter == "B").value') #>> '{}' as b
from the_table;
```

`jsonb_path_query_first()` returns a `jsonb` value. Unfortunately there is no easy or direct cast to `text`. The `#>> '{}'` achieves this.